# getElementById no longer works after redesign of html code

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is odd, this js code worked perfectly yesterday. All I did was redesign the html and changed ID's in the html and the JS code. It says that the onclick for the first button can't be null which is odd because i wait until the page is loaded until the js runs. Any ideas? Even weirder is that the code works perfectly in the codesnippet plugin.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    alert("Hello World.This page is loaded!")
});


/**
* @type HTMLInputElement
*/
const message = document.getElementById('battleLog')
/**
* @type HTMLInputElement
*/
const reply = document.getElementById('combatLog')

var MonsterNames = ["Ogre", "Troll", "Rat", "Goblin"]
var MonsterSpawn = Math.floor(Math.random() * MonsterNames.length)
var Monster = MonsterNames[MonsterSpawn]
var MonsterHp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99)
var AttackDmg = 0

document.getElementById('spawnButton').onclick = spawnMonster
function spawnMonster() {
    MonsterHp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99)
    MonsterSpawn = Math.floor(Math.random() * MonsterNames.length)
    Monster = MonsterNames[MonsterSpawn]
    reply.value = Monster + "\n" + "Monster hp:" + MonsterHp
}


reply.value = "Monster hp:" + MonsterHp
document.getElementById('attackButton').onclick = chatBot
function chatBot() {
    AttackDmg = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
    MonsterHp -= AttackDmg
    if (MonsterHp <= 0) {
        reply.value = "You killed the monster!"
    }
    else {
        reply.value = Monster + "\n" + "Monster hp:" + MonsterHp
        message.value = "You did " + AttackDmg + " damage to the monster"
    }

}
```

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-areas:
        "BattleInfo"
        "CombatStats";
}

.BattleInfo {
    grid-area: BattleInfo;
}

.CombatStats {
    grid-area: CombatStats;
}


html,
body,
.container {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
button{
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="chatBot.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="BattleInfo"><textarea name="battleLog" id="battleLog" cols="30" rows="10" readonly>NULL AND VOID</textarea></div>
        <div class="CombatStats"><textarea name="combatLog" id="combatLog" cols="30" rows="10" readonly>NULL AND VOID</textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="attackButton">ATTACK</button>
        <button type="button" id="spawnButton">SPAWN MONSTER</button>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add `defer` to your `<script src="chatBot.js"></script>` and see what happens. So for example: `<script src="chatBot.js" defer></script>`. Using the defer keyword is used for the DOM to load before executing the JavaScript functions

Comment: That seemed to work :) Odd since it seems to do the same thing as my javascript function in the beginning. But if it works it works! Thanks

Comment: Your onload function doesn’t include anything except the alert. It needs to encompass the getElementById etc calls.